# Problem with dropdown and codeigniter

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, drop-down-menu

i'm using 2 dropdowns where the second gets populated from the first choice.
My problem is that i'm not getting the value from the first dropdown.
What i get is [object Object].
Here's the javascript and php code:
Thanks.

Javascript:

```
function getState(){
$("#selectestate").bind("change",function(){

    $("#selectcity").load("results/ajaxcity", {stat: $(this).val()} ); //This is where the problem is
    alert({stat: $(this).val()});//Shows [object Object]
});
return false;

}
```

PHP:

```
$curstat=$this -> input -> post('state'); //current selected state in first dropdown
<tr>        
    <?php $js = 'id="selectstate" onChange="getState();"';?>
    <td><h3> State: </h3></td>
    <td id="selectestate"><?php echo form_dropdown('state', $stat, $curstat, $js);?></td> 
</tr>    
<tr>    
    <td><h3> City: </h3></td>
    <td id="selectcity"><?php echo form_dropdown('city', $cit);?></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to alter this code:

```
$("#selectestate").bind("change",function(){
```

to this:

```
$("#selectestate select").bind("change",function(){
```

You are asking for the value of the `<td id="selectstate">` ... which is of course `null`.  `#selectstate select` loads the actual `<select>` element that you are looking for, which will then enable you to get its value.

You will also want to change `$("#selectcity")` to `$("#selectcity select")` to avoid the same problem in your anonymous function.

Finally, your alert is behaving as expected. `{}` defines an object in Javascript.  So you are alerting an object containing a single attribute.  Just `alert($(this).val());// Should show the value`

If it still fails it's because either:

A) Your URL is wrong
or
B) There is something wrong with the php function called by `results/ajaxcity`

### EDIT:

---

*Smacks head*: I should have caught this.  In your code you have this function:

```
1.    function getState(){
2.    $("#selectestate select").bind("change",function(){
3.    
4.        $("#selectcity select").load("results/ajaxcity", {stat: $(this).val()} ); 
5.        alert($(this).val());
6.        });
7.    return false;
8.    }
```

Your generated HTML looks something like this:

```
<select name="state" id="selectstate" onChange="getState();">
```

**THE PROBLEM:** When you use the `<select>` for the first time your function is called and jQuery binds an anonymous function to the change event for select (line #2) that will be executed every time the change event fires from this select **from now on**.  Every time you select the dropdown a new anonymous function is bound by line #2 and **all** of the functions that are currently bound to the dropdown are executed. (So if you use the dropdown N times the "change" function will fire N-1 times.)

**THE SOLUTION:** Use [`$(document).ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3) to [bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) your function.  Your restructured code will look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getState(element){
    $("#selectcity select").load("results/ajaxcity", {stat: $(element).val()} );
    alert($(element).val());
    return false;
}
</script>
//... snip ...
<?php $js = 'id="selectstate"';?>
//... snip ...
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#selectestate select").bind("change", getState);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. One thing that i've found was that if i put setTimeout(getState)  the function works the first time.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `value` for `td` element, which you are accessing in `"#selectestate"` selector. Instead of `{stat: $(this).val()}` you should find inner `select` element `{stat: $(this).find("select").val()}`

Comment: Still get Object.
What can i do?

Answer (score 0):

You're loading the .val() of a `<td>` element (`$(this)`, inside your handler for a TD). You need to get the id of the `<select>` tag.

If you really can't find the ID (or codeigniter doesn't set it.. impossible to tell from your example since form_dropdown() is creating it), then instead of `$(this).val()` you could try `$('select',this).val()` which will find the value of the first `<select>` tag within the TD.

Also in your debugging, `{stat: $(this).val()}` *is* an object, so of course that's what alert() shows you. Try using firebug, and then change alert() to console.log() -- the firebug console will show you the full object. You could also simply do alert($(this).val()) -- though realize of course that it will be wrong due to the first paragraph above.

Comment: Here's what i get from the source view:

<td><h3> State: </h3></td> 
<td><select name="state"> 
<option value="State1">State1</option> 
<option value="State2">State2</option> 
<option value="State3">State3</option> 
</select></td> 

Using firebug i only get Object.
Thanks.

Comment: Ok just digg down and found that the id is the one being generated in the $js variable:


<td><h3> State: </h3></td>

<td><select name="state" id="selectstate" onChange="getState();">

<option value="State1">State1</option> <option value="State2">State2</option> <option value="State3">State3</option> </select></td>